# jQuery $("#Div").height() returns undefined

Tags: jquery, html, angularjs

### The problem

It seems that jQuery is loaded and running but that the elements it's trying to work with (the `<div>`s) are not yet available so it just returns undefined. The issue might be that the project contains the AngularJS framework which also utilizes the `$` symbol. Knowing this I modified my jQuery code to start with `jQuery(document).ready(function($) { ...` but it didn't seem to solve the problem. I also added the `jQuery.noConflict();` which also didn't help. I also tried this pattern:

```
var $j = jQuery.noConflict();
// $j is now an alias to the jQuery function; creating the new alias is optional.

$j(document).ready(function() {
    $j( "div" ).hide();
});
```

That didn't work as well. I tried moving the scripts around in the `index.html` putting jQuery and `bootstrap.min.js`(because bootstrap depends on jQuery) at the bottom, or at the top, or middle of the scripts. That changes the outcome but it is still the wrong outcome. I sometimes get `undefined undefined undefined 0` as outcome from the `console.log()` about the heights of all the `div`s.

Very strange problem. Before I tried doing this with jQuery I actually just used JavaScript but then I tried jQuery because I read about the `ready()` method, because I thought that the HTML elements themselves weren't "ready" yet to be worked with.

Note: The `$("#contentDivision")` is the most important feature of the issue because it is dynamically populated thus its height changes as the document loads, meaning that the jQuery needs to load after the `$("#contentDivision")` has been filled up with all the text and pictures (it's a blog).

Another thing that leads me to this line of thinking is that writing the exact same jQuery code which is in my main.js in the chrome console produces the correct result.

I also need help with creating some kind of listener or something to dynamically re-run the jQuery script so the window resizes its height for each type of screen appropriately.

Any help is appreciated, thank you.

### main.js (containing my jQuery code)

```
jQuery.noConflict();
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
console.log('jQuery(document) is ready');
console.log($(window).height());   // returns height of browser viewport
console.log($(document).height()); // returns height of HTML document
console.log(
    $("#panelDivision").height() + " " +
    $("#scrollDivision").height() + " " +
    $("#contentDivision").height() + " " +
    $("#extraDivision").height()
);

var $max = Math.max($("#contentDivision").height(), $("#extraDivision").height());
console.log($max);

$("#scrollDivision").height($max - $("#panelDivision").height());
$("#contentDivision").height($max);
$("#extraDivision").height($max);
});
```

### The output I'm getting from jQuery

```
jQuery(document) is ready
949
1299
75 0 undefined 800
NaN
```

### index.html (css links and meta tags omitted)

```
<body ng-app="myApp">
<div class="main_container">
<navbar></navbar>
<div class="container-fluid page-wrap">
    <div class="row">
        <div id="leftDivision" class="col-md-3 paddingRemove side-posts">
            <posts></posts>
        </div>
        <div id="contentDivision" class="col-md-7 paddingRemove white-container" ng-view></div>
        <div id="extraDivision" class="col-md-2 paddingRemove white-container">
            <lorem></lorem>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<foobar></foobar>
</div>

<!-- Imported JavaScript Files -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.4/angular-route.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.4/angular-sanitize.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<!-- Local Angular-related JavaScript Files -->
<script src="client/js/app.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="client/js/main.controller.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="client/js/auth.controller.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="client/js/blog.controller.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="client/js/directives.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="client/js/filters.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="client/js/factories.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script src="client/js/main.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: My angularJS time is quite a time ago but I know ng-view which you use on`contentDivision` does in the first step only create a comment in the dom. Only after inseration the div gets created. https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/directive/ngView Read here about it, I cant explain it so I cant grant an proper answer

Comment: I cant see id="Div" into the html.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with `ng-view` rendering concepts.

> [**`ngView`**](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/directive/ngView) is a directive that complements the $route service by including the rendered template of the current route into the main layout (index.html) file. Every time the current route changes, the included view changes with it according to the configuration of the $route service.

---

In your code, you are using `ng-view` on that div. So that div (Dom Element) will be rendered after any route changes are done. otherwise the div element will not rendered, which means you can't see the div tag in html page source. That's why you are getting undefined.

---

So you could try this below.

```
<div id="contentDivision" class="col-md-7 
paddingRemove white-container">
<div ng-view></div>
</div>
```

Comment: That's a good tip, but the console still logs `75 0 137 800` where 137 is the pixel height of the content, meaning it isn't filled up with text and pictures.

Comment: @AquaSolid It depend on your main div height not by the content. I think it may taking from `contentDivision` div class. Kindly accept my answer if it's helps your.

Comment: @AquaSolid But I don't know what you mean by `meaning it isn't filled up with text and pictures`??

Comment: With this suggestion you are getting the pixel value before the ng-view has been rendered. However you need the height afterwards. Instead of running your logic on ready you will need to find a way to run your logic after the ui-view has loaded.

Comment: Then he should be check if the `ng-view` rendered or not.

Answer (score 0):

Load the jQuery script before the AngularJS script:

```
<!-- Imported JavaScript Files -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.4/angular-route.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.4/angular-sanitize.min.js"></script>
```

Although I have to say, you don't even need the jQuery since AngularJS can do all of what you want anyway.

Comment: Weirdly I haven't thought about that much. How would you go about doing that? Something with `$scope` probably. I don't have much experience with this, sorry.